# The impossible html layout?

Tags: html, css, tablelayout

I'm attempting to create a page layout similar to what is shown below (CSS only with support for Chrome, Firefox, IE8+)

Note: columns 1,2,3 can all dynamically grow (e.g. appending markup from xhr etc) and they should all be the same height (the height of the largest column). Also, cell 4 can also grow although should only be the height of its internal content.

```
 _______________
|   |_____4_____|
|   |       |   |
| 1 |   2   | 3 |
|   |       |   |
|___|_______|___|
```

I'm having a problem achieving this cross browser.

**My Attempt:**
I've created a simplified **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cku7y/)** example to show my attempt using tables (using rowspan / colspan) to get the desired layout. 
I suppose this is in essence a multi column css layout with a twist...

Although tables should generally not be used for layout. It seemed to be the least hacky way of achieving the desired results cross browser.

I've used a js timeout to adjust the height of one of the columns (to simulate dynamic appending of content).

**Problem with my attempt:**

In Firefox (and IE9/ IE8), cell '4'  (**green cell** in jsfiddle) will not respect its set pixel height (height becomes larger) when column 1 (red cell) grows dynamically. View the fiddle in Firefox to see the issue. Why does cell 4 grow when cell 1's height is updated?

This is NOT a problem in Chrome.

Comment: Flexbox...end of discussion.

Comment: I need to support IE8 & IE9, so flexbox is out.

Comment: check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2xa2R/1/) not a solution but could become if you try to improve it. I just couldn't manage the height of the two and three columns.

Comment: Thanks Mr_Green but all heights of the three columns must be equal, which is why i initially used a <table> approach...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the technique described in this [article](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-solving-the-equal-height-column-conundrum--cms-20403) Andrew added in a comment above, I was able to create a workable cross-browser (well IE8+) solution you can find - [**here**](http://jsfiddle.net/8Ywj3/)

The markup is pretty simple and requires no tables

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="leftCol">left col
        <div class="leftColContent"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="header">header</div>
    <div class="centerCol">center col</div>
    <div class="rightCol">right col</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something like this be of any help?

http://jsfiddle.net/cku7y/5/

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="red"></div>
    <div class="green"></div>
    <div class="blue"></div>
    <div class="violet"></div>    
</div>
```

(check jsfiddle css)
It can of course be improved, but it's a start without using tables.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Andrew, I initially tried this approach, but it involves setting a fixed height on the wrapper. Which I cannot do.

Comment: I think this is what you should look into:
http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/

There are several solutions

Comment: Thanks Andrew, read through that before posting here and it doesn't provide a workable solution for the header of the right-side two columns..

Comment: Hey again, stumbled upon this one:

http://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/quick-tip-solving-the-equal-height-column-conundrum--cms-20403

Comment: Good find! was able to use that Works in IE8+, firefox etc. Will post a working example shortly

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you can do it this way.

http://jsfiddle.net/V3ta3/2/

Set a double container and you don't need any fixed values.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="column1">
        <p>Column 1</p>
    </div>
    <div class="wrap-right-side">
        <div class="column4">
            <p>Column 4</p>
        </div>
        <div class="right-side">
            <div class="column2">
                <p>Column 2</p>
            </div>
            <div class="column3">
                <p>Column 4</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- end right side -->
    </div>
    <!-- end wrap right side -->
</div>
<!-- end wrapper -->
</div>
<!-- end container -->
```

This only problem is the float preventing the full height of the red column. So you need to find a way to clear the float.

Comment: As said before, the three columns must grow together and be of the same height.